# Deleting millions on records while using log shipping - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm not very familiar with log shipping and I need to delete 70 million records from a table that contains 71 million records.

My issue is how will log shipping react if I do the following:

1. Copy the million records that I want to keep, in a new table
2. Truncate the original table (Truncate Table OriginalTable)
3. Insert in the original table the million of records

We have limited space for the logs. What will be logged and shipped?

Thanks

Comment: I assume you should delete from the Primary database and the log shipping will reflect the changes

Comment: You can also create a new table, name it Shipping_NEW or something and just insert the records you want to keep directly into it from your production table. Then rename the old table to something like Shipping_BAK... rename Shipping_NEW to Shipping (making it the production table). This saves you the log space from doing two inserts. Nominal if you ask me but since you seemed concerned it's another option. Then you can drop or keep your old table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fine - as long as you're not truncating the log, and just truncating the table, log shipping should keep up.

Truncates are logged, just logged efficiently (see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55834/what-does-a-truncate-table-write-to-the-log-file-in-sql-server/55882).  You will get logging for the million inserts, but this is probably about as efficient as you can get.

Comment: Thanks, following your answer I was confident to go ahead with my procedure. I all went well, the log file was only 225mb, for the truncate and  insert of close to a million records.